# OleDbDataReader lock file

Tags: c#, oledbdatareader

I am using a oledbDataReader in C# to read data from  a FoxPro database. What I would like to know is, does this lock the table that it is currently reading from?  If so, how can I read from the table without locking the table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No way. Close datareader and connection and file will be unlocked.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan does this mean the file is actually getting locked and there is no way to read from it without it getting locked? thanks for answering so quick

Comment: When you have open connection on file (Fxopro DB) it will be locked until connection still open.

Comment: Thanks @HamletHakobyan. Will copying the file to another destination and then reading it from there work? the service is hitting the database every 30 seconds and it takes about a minute to read the data.